# Quitting job right before probation ends

Tags: internship, resignation, probation, first-job, graduate

I'm a fresh grad with no job experience but have a hands on skill that I think makes me job ready. I did applied for a job, got selected, got offered a paid internship in order to access me atleast 3 months. Now I'm almost done with my 3 months and my employer has made arrangements to take a look at me again which we may sit behind contract table again next week but I don't feel like continuing nor accepting what ever offer they will bring up because:

1. My role within the last 3 months was not challenging enough to teach me more, and I feel I can't progress in my career. ( The job description is a bit different from my role now and best fit role is already filled and is either I maintain my current role or quit )
2. Even though I did my best with what ever task I was assigned to, i was still not happy because of the task level.
3. I realized that I will be employed to this role fulltime but I wouldn't be happy with my job if that happens.
4. Company's culture  ( compulsory religious things ) and in-job-politics.
5. Afraid of being underpaid because of my no job experience.

With all said, I decided to start applying for a new job else where late last month, this time too I got selected, got through the interview,  got selected because of my skill set and some works,  now I was offered 2x the amount I'm  being paid for the internship with a status probation  ( 50% increments in salary after successful probation ). I have discussed this with my line manager and he thinks I should go for it if Im okay with the decision yet he has already filed my appraisal report for fulltime employment. I have already made my decision of moving on but I don't know what to do regarding to who I should inform first, the HR or my supervisor  (head of department).

My contract allows me to quit anytime without any formal reason but I don't want to use that means.

Comment: Just to confirm, have you already received an offer for a full-time position, or are you just expecting to get one?

Comment: expecting to receive from my current company but I have received one from my last interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have not yet received an offer for a full-time position at the place of your current internship, but you do have an offer from another company, you can proceed in one of the following ways:

- If you're keen on joining the new company and know that there's nothing that can keep you at your current place - go ahead and accept the offer. If both you and your new company are fine with you starting the job after your internship is over, then there's nothing else to do. Otherwise, if you plan to start earlier, you'd need to talk to your current supervisor, tell them that you would like to quit before the end of your internship and discuss the details, such as notice period if applicable.
- In case if you're willing to consider the full-time offer from your current company - talk to your supervisor and let them know that you've received an offer from somewhere else but you're interested in a full-time position at your current company. If they're interested they'll make you an offer and you can compare the two options you have.

If you go with the first option and eventually get an offer from your current company - politely decline and explain that you've already accepted another offer. No need to go into much detail about the reasons, saying that you feel that the new company is a better fit for you is enough.

Comment: Cool, I think I can wait for the 25th then decline the offer, so I don't say much...